# Typescript error: Property 'flat' does not exist on type '[string, unknown][]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to use .flat() on an array, but Typescript claims:

> Property 'flat' does not exist on type '[string, unknown][]'

I've added "es2019 to my tsconfig file:

```js
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2019", "dom"],
```

The function where flat() is used is:

```js
const legendSeries = (series) => {
    const formattedSeries = {};
    series.map((serie) =>
      Object.entries(serie).map((s) => {
        if (s[0] in formattedSeries) {
          return (formattedSeries[s[0]].count += s[1]);
        }
        return (formattedSeries[s[0]] = { id: s[0], label: s[0], count: s[1] });
      })
    );
    return Object.entries(formattedSeries)
      .flat()
      .filter((_, i) => i % 2 !== 0);
  };
```

The error persists. How to fix this (it's a React project in case it might be helpful)?

Answer (score 6):

I think this issue is because typescript doesn't have access to array.flat(), in such a case it will throw an error of not have knowledge of flat(), as mentioned above by @codejockie. You need to update your config file like
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ]
  }
}`

we need to add es2019 or es2019.array to --lib setting for TypeScript so that it starts  recognizing array.flat() and flatMap().

After making the changes. Please restart your project if the changes don't reflect.

Comment: The key for me was to close Visual Studio Code and then start it again.  After that TypeScript stopped complaining

Answer (score 0):

Update your `lib` to this `"lib": ["es2019", "es2017", "es7", "es6", "dom"]`.

This is my config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "es2017",
      "es7",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "declaration": true /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */,
    "outDir": "dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "examples", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: The issue persists. Typescript keeps whining.

Comment: I added my config for you to reference

Comment: I have "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "es2019", "es6", "es7", "dom"] . It makes no sense TS returns an error.